# Error using Axios on react-native network error

Tags: ios, react-native, axios

I'm using Axios in my code and when i try to send data for a API, in the console a message appears "Error network error"

This is my codes:

```
  salvar() {

   axios.post('http://easypasse.com.br/gestao/wsCadastrar.php',
   { nome: this.state.nome, cpf: this.state.cpf, senha: this.state.senha, method: 'app-set-usuario', "plataforma": 'ios'},
   {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
   })
   .then(function(response){
   console.log(response)
   })
  .catch(function(error) {
   console.log('Erro ' + error.message);
  });
}
```

And here is my info.plist
[image: info.plist]

Why that problem?

Answer (score 0):

This might happen because you're using http instead of https.

As per discussion below, also try closing everything and clearing your RN cache.

Comment: Even with the info.plist setted with "App Transport Security Settings" ?

Comment: ooh, that should be fine. I've also had this and I had to close my emulator + react-native-debugger, clear react-native cache, and I think that helped. Also my api keys were missing at some point, but I think that was an unrelated problem. a xcode project clean never hurts either

Comment: What do you suggest? Close everything (Xcode and React-Native) and open again?

Comment: 1. check your post is right (use postman and pass in exactly what you're sending)
2. close everything, clear RN cache

Comment: I already got it. I close all aplications, Xcode end React-Native, re-open again and works.